# Use of dstCn in cvtColor of OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to figure out the use of the argument dstCn in the API cvtColor of OpenCV.

Consider imageMat1 as a 512*512 of 3 channel matrix representing BGR values. When executing the following statements,

cv::cvtColor(imageMat1,outputImage1,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB,4);
cv::cvtColor(imageMat1,outputImage2,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB,2);

outputImage1.channels() and outputImage2.channels() both returns 3 as outputs.

The output values of these matrixes(ie, outputImage1, outputImage2) don't have any differences, so what's the use of specifying 4 or 2 ?